# Dúvida flexbox? HTML e CSS

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Olá, poderiam me ajudar? Não consigo colocar uma interface do lado da outra, já tentei usar o flex, flexbox e até o inline, e mesmo assim ela fica com uma embaixo da outra. Gostaria de colocar 3 uma ao lado da outra(no codigo que estarei enviando só tem 2). Logo, gostaria que me ajudassem nesse probleminha, ficarei muito grato. Vi alguns vídeos mas mesmo assim nao consegui resolver, sempre altera a forma do produto ou algo do tipo.

```css
.catalogo {
    width: 1100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 50px 0;
    
}
    
.catalogo li {
    text-align: center;
    width: 30%;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin: 0 1.5%;
    padding: 30px 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 2px solid #000000;
    border-radius: 10px;
    display: flex;
}
```

```html
<main>           
    <ul class="catalogo">
        <li>
            <h2>Trilhas Rio de Janeiro</h2>
            <img src="RJ.png">
        </li>
    </ul>
</main>
    
<main> 
    <ul class="catalogo">
        <li>
            <h2>Trilhas São Paulo</h2>
            <img src="SP.png">
        </li>
    </ul>
</main>
```

Comment: já testou colocar na classe que você dá display-flex, adicionar flex-direction:row ou flex-wrap: wrap?

Comment: tentei agora, mas continuou a mesma coisa

Comment: Bruno, primeiramente é importante que você conheça melhor o HTML. Por questões semânticas e também de acessibilidade, não é aconselhável inserir mais de um elemento <main> no documento. Leia: https://github.com/frontendbr/forum/issues/30. Além disso, tb falta vc entender melhor o funcionamento do CSS. Visto que está aplicando um width fixo e bem grande nas duas tags com classe "catalogo". Isso confunde e deixa mais difícil de entender o que você realmente quer fazer. Sugiro pesquisar sobre CSS Grid e posicionamentos utilizando o CSS. É um tópico essencial para construir layouts. Boa sorte!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você só precisa adicionar um elemento com `display: flex` contendo estes dois elementos...

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.catalogo {
  width: 300px;
}
    
.catalogo li {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding: 30px 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 2px solid #000000;
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>           
    <ul class="catalogo">
      <li>
        <h2>Trilhas Rio de Janeiro</h2>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div> 
    <ul class="catalogo">
      <li>
        <h2>Trilhas São Paulo</h2>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado!